# Spring Boot JUnit 5 test with @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) not working - mocks are null, MockitoJUnitRunner is working

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I just migrated my project from Spring Boot 2.1 to 2.3 and thus have now JUnit 5 (with vintage) in place (also including mockito-core and mockito-junit-jupiter of version 3.3.3).
While all JUnit 4 tests are working fine my first JUnit 5 tests is not working correctly:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private Some to;

    @Mock
    private SomeProperties properties;

    @Test
    public void applied() {
         ....
         //properties is null -> NPE
         when(properties.getSome()).thenReturn("some");
         ....
    }
```

The mocks are not injected (NPE in when statement). If i switch to old JUnit 4 style `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` all is working fine.

So probably the old runner or vintage runner is used?

How to fix this and get tests with "@ExtendWith" working? I thought i can migrate step by step - let new tests run with junit5 runner.

Comment: Do you use Mockito or Mockito2?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.3.0 draws mockito-core and mockito-junit-jupiter of version 3.3.3 (updated question)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct import of `@Test` for JUnit 5? See also https://hackernoon.com/mixing-junit4-and-junit5-2da44956de8c for some info on combining JUnit 4 and 5.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe thats it: used the wrong import for test - all the migration guides i read were not mentioning this detail :-P. please make this an answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ensure you use the correct import for the `@Test` annotation:

- JUnit 4: `org.junit.Test`
- JUnit 5: `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

Comment: Thank you! This is really easy to overlook.

Comment: After trying using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) It works!
Probably it's a dependencies problem.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem when migrating an old JUnit 4 code base.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `maven` and expect that tests run during `mvn install`, then upgrading `maven-surefire-plugin` may help. With old `maven-surefire-plugin`, the tests would be ignored and `mvn install` produce output similar to below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running pl.somecompany.foo.FirstTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in pl.somecompany.foo.FirstTest
Running pl.somecompany.foo.SecondTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in pl.somecompany.foo.SecondTest
Running pl.somecompany.foo.ThirdTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in pl.somecompany.foo.ThirdTest

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Upgrade `maven-surefire-plugin` version in your `pom.xml` (use the latest compatible with your Java version):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
</plugin>
```